# ASP.NET: avoid RequiredFieldValidator on navigate button postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have an ASPX page with two RequiredFieldValidator and a button to go to another page. This button must do a postback to know where to go. This button can be clicked it any time.

The problem is that the RequiredFieldValidators are not disabled and show their message asking for a value.

Is there any way to avoid validation when the user click this special button?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set CausesValidation to false on the special button, or put the RequiredFieldValidators in a ValidationGroup with whatever should cause the validation. (The button that should cause validation and the validators should all be in the same validation group) The first option should work and be the quickest.

Comment: I've used the first option. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

CausesValidation="false"

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `ValidationGroup` to the controls.

On the submit button you also add a `Validationgroup`